# Return only the highest-valued row

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to find a solution to only returns the highest-valued row from a SQL query

I have a query that joins two tables together and then checks how many times the id matches within the different tables (within 'athelete' the `id` param is unique).

```
SELECT t.athlete_id, count(a.id) as 'Number of activities' FROM training_session t
    INNER JOIN athlete a ON t.athlete_id = a.id
    WHERE t.athlete_id = a.id
    GROUP BY a.id
```

The following table is returned

```
athlete_id    Number of activities     
1                         4
2                         1
3                         1
4                         1
5                         1
6                         1
```

The issued problem is that I only want to return the row with the highest number of activities. According to the table above this should be 
`athlete_id = 1` since it has the greatest amount of activities.

I would appreciate some pointers on how I could improve my query to match these queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT t.athlete_id, count(*) as `Number of activities`
FROM training_session t INNER JOIN
     athlete a
     ON t.athlete_id = a.id
GROUP BY t.athlete_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I don't think a `JOIN` is needed for this query:

```
SELECT t.athlete_id, COUNT(*) as `Number of activities`
FROM training_session t 
GROUP BY t.athlete_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And if you want all rows in the event of ties, then this requires a bit more work.  I would recommend ranking functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.athlete_id, COUNT(*) as `Number of activities`,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM training_session t 
      GROUP BY t.athlete_id
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely some interesting solutions. Interesting to see someone with more experience building up the queries and see how you can layer them to form the solution. 

This will work perfectly!